# Xamarin iOS building on windows with mac connected. Is there a way to access mac files during the build?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building iOS project using Windows that is connected to Mac.

I need to add a target that will copy some libraries from ${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/
into app bundle
how to access them from *.targets file?

```
<Target Name="_CopySwiftLibraries">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_SwiftLibsDevice Include="[How to specify a path properly to access the files by path above?]" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" SourceFiles="@(_SwiftLibsDevice)" DestinationFolder="$(_AppBundlePath)Frameworks" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: It seems not possible , Apple not allows to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out once it connected to the mac it works in the scope of mac and normal path will work
$(_SdkDevPath)\Toolchains\XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\usr\lib\swift\iphoneos\libswiftCore.dylib